# How to pass a variable in the procedure of application on time?

Tags: excel, vba, ontime

Can anyone explain how I can transfer the for loop counter x as an argument of sub `email_send` in `application.ontime` procedure.

Find attached the code I have written to send email reminder on the basis of different types of drawing.

```
Dim x As Long

Sub drawings()
    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(x, "F") = "Type-1" And Cells(x, "H") = "" Then
            Cells(x, "H").Value = 1
            time1 = Now() + TimeValue("00:02:00")
            Application.OnTime time1, "'email_send" & x & "'"
        ElseIf Cells(x, "F") = "Type-2" And Cells(x, "H") = "" Then
            Cells(x, "H").Value = 1
            time2 = Now() + TimeValue("00:04:00")
            Application.OnTime time2, "'email_send" & x & "'"
        ElseIf Cells(x, "F") = "Type-3" And Cells(x, "H") = "" Then
            Cells(x, "H").Value = 1
            time3 = Now() + TimeValue("00:08:00")        
            Application.OnTime time3, "'email_send" & x & "'"
        ElseIf Cells(x, "F") = "Type-4" And Cells(x, "H") = "" Then
            Cells(x, "H").Value = 1
            time4 = Now() + TimeValue("00:10:00")        
            'time4 = time4 + 5        
            Application.OnTime time4, "'email_send" & x & "'"
            MsgBox time4
        End If

        MsgBox Cells(x, "A")        
    Next x
End Sub



Sub email_send(ByVal x As Long)
    Dim OutApp As Object       
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        'MsgBox "hello"
        .To = Cells(2, 9).Value
        .Subject = "Case ID " & Cells(x, "A") & " (" & Cells(x, "B") & ") Deadline Approaching"
        .Body = "Please complete your assigned drawing asap."
        .Display
        .Send
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA, so I request you guys to find mistakes in my code and suggest edits.

Edit:
Thank you for guiding me through the steps,  but  the problem is I'm getting an unexpected error when I follow them. I wanted to attach the photo of the error but I can't because I don't have enough points.

Comment: check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime
you cannot pass arguments to the procedure.

Comment: I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and to declare **all** your variables properly.

Answer (score 0):

When calling a sub you can pass arguments.

```
Sub email_send(x as variant) 
'your code here
End sub
x = 3
email_send x
```

Or you can declare x as a public variable :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables

Comment: But when I call application.ontime time1, "email_send(x)" it gives an error. How can I pass x value with procedure "email_send" ?

Comment: Why using application.ontime ? "'email_send x'" for arguments (double-quote then quote). For more arguments it would be "'email_send x, y, z'".

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to change the signature for `email_send` so that it includes a parameter that accepts a Long...

```
Sub email_send(ByVal x As Long)
```

Then you can pass your argument as follows...

```
Application.OnTime time1, "'email_send " & x & "'"
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the syntax. I did as you said but it is giving an error that macro email_send2 doesn't exists, and the macro may not be available in this workbook or may be disabled.

Comment: In your posted code, the macro is named `email_send`, however you're calling `email_send2`, hence the error.

Comment: Actually I am not calling email_send2, as you can see in my code. The x value which I'm trying to pass with email_send procedure is 2 at that time, similary x value increases with every next x and the error becomes email_send3 not found. So this means that the method you have specified above, doesn't send x value as argument of the sub, instead x gets adds to sub's name, which compiler later fails to recognize later.

Comment: I had tested it before posting it, and it does indeed pass the variable to `email_send`.  Check to make sure that you have copied the syntax exactly.

Comment: Make sure that you've include the single apostrophes (') within the double quotes ("").

Comment: I have edited my code above according to your suggestion. As you can see I have written it exactly as you have suggested, but still I'm getting the same error as I mentioned above.

Comment: I looked into other similar threads, and saw people suggesting the same method as you have suggested above. I just don't know why it isn't working for me

Comment: Here's a link to a sample [workbook](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Atmin3kqXqL0gi3iItuoCWbH5RpL), which contains an example that runs successfully.  Does it work for you?  If not, do you get an error?  If so, which line causes the error, and what type of error is it?

Comment: It is working perfectly in your workbook. I don't know ! I'm doing the exact same thing, then why is it giving error? How can I attach my workbook here, just like you did, so you can see what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Thank you domenic for helping me out. It's now working perfectly. I was not giving space between email_send procedure and ". It works flawlessly now. Thank you once again

Comment: Domenic can you help me on one more thing please. How can I make this code run automatically at regular intervals so timers could be started for newly entered data, and would this, rerunning of code, resets my timers for already existing cases.